# to store and keep values of variable even after event is finished in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

this code is called upon a button click in a windows form and the values are stored after button click and disappear after the event ends and go back to default values but I want the values to remain as i have to use them somewhere else....any suggestions?Also I want to retain the current state of the form and not use a new instance each time
 showval function called and the value of variable bitwise is changed there

```
class Profile{
public bool GetProfileFilter()
    {
        frmInactiveView frmInactive = new frmInactiveView();
        if (frmInactive.btnApplyWasClicked == true || frmInactive.btnCancelWasClicked == false)
        {
            frmInactive.ShowVal();
            MessageBox.Show("bit:" + IBitWise);
            MessageBox.Show("ST:" + BegDate);
            MessageBox.Show("ET:" + EndDate);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }    
    }
```

}

```
enter code here
public partial class FilterView : Form{

  Profile profile = new Profile();
  private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnApplyWasClicked = true;
        ShowVal();
        status = profile.GetProfileFilter();
        profile.ShowMe();
        Btn_Enable();
        this.Close();
    }
    public void ShowVal()
    {
        if (btnApplyWasClicked == true || btnCancelWasClicked == false)
        {
            if (chkCancel.Checked == true)
            {
                profile.IBitWise += 2;
            }
            if (chkDiscon.Checked == true)
            {
                profile.IBitWise += 1;
            }
            if (chkVoidwoRes.Checked == true)
            {
                profile.IBitWise += 4;
            }
            if (chkVoidwRes.Checked == true)
            {
                profile.IBitWise += 8;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Note that in markdown `>` indicates that you're quoting someone or something, so it looked like your entire question text was a quote.

Comment: Which instance's value you want to keep? Is it `frmInactiveView`? If yes, put `frmInactiveView` as an class member rather than keep it in the scope of function. It seems your post mixing of two class. You need to clarify which part belongs to which class.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  [Edit] your post and tell us what values you want persisted.  We need to see where/how you declare and set those values.  You probably need to show us your on button click code.

Comment: @LouisGo  Yes they are in two different classes I have edited them and if  I put the object outside the class what help would that be of?

Comment: @jwdonahue I have edited the question and i want the values to persist even after the event is complete(i.e button click) the values are declared in class profile..... and are set in the form

Comment: You need to perserve instance in where `GetProfileFilter` getting called. Post the code (or a minimal class) calling `GetProfileFilter` would help as well.

Comment: @LouisGo preserve it how? could you please elaborate...the button click event class calls getprofile filter...which is already posted

Comment: @Chirag Post the minimal class which is calling `GetProfileFilter` so there would be detail I could help.

Comment: @LouisGo the form frmInactiveView is calling GetProfileFilter in the form i've declared Profile profile = new Profile(); the class which contains GetProfileFilter as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your form getting instantiated every time when `GetProfileFileter` is called.

To avoid it, put instance of `frmInactiveView` under your `Profile` class. Then value of `frmInactiveView` would only be renewed when a new `Profile` is instantiated.

```
class Profile{
    // Keep your form instance here
    frmInactiveView frmInactive = new frmInactiveView();

public bool GetProfileFilter()
    {
        // Don't new it again!
        //frmInactiveView frmInactive = new frmInactiveView();
        DialogResult result = frmInactive.ShowDialog();

        // You may need to take care of dialog result if someone clicked cancel.


        if (frmInactive.btnApplyWasClicked == true || frmInactive.btnCancelWasClicked == false)
        {
            frmInactive.ShowVal();
            MessageBox.Show("bit:" + IBitWise);
            MessageBox.Show("ST:" + BegDate);
            MessageBox.Show("ET:" + EndDate);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: it is throwing a stackoverflowexception

Comment: Then your post code is not providing enough details. It should not be stack overflowed unless something is calling nested.